# Maximum eigenvalue of an adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph without multiple edges.
Additionally, let $|V| = n + 1$, where $n \geq 3$.
$G$ is created in such a way, that $n$-first vertices create a cycle and $n+1$ vertex is connected only to the previous $n$-vertices.

Prove that the maximum eigenvalue of adjacency matrix generated by this graph is equal:

$$
\lambda_{0} = \sqrt{n+1} + 1
$$

---

**Example.** Let $n+1 = 10$. The $G$ looks like this - [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmbmd.png)]. The adjacency matrix $M$ for $G$ is the following:

$$
M = 
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

The characteristics polynomial $W$ of $M$:

$$
W = \lambda^{10} - 18\lambda^8 - 18\lambda^7 + 72\lambda^6 + 90\lambda^5 - 93\lambda^4 - 126\lambda^3 + 27\lambda^2 + 34\lambda - 9
$$

Lastly, real roots of $W$ are the following:

$$
\begin{array}{lar}
\lambda_0 = 1 + \sqrt{10} \\
\lambda_1 = -1  \\
\lambda_2 = 1 - \sqrt{10} \\
\end{array}
$$

Of course, $\lambda_0$ satisfies the equality $\lambda_0 = \sqrt{n+1} + 1 = \sqrt{10} + 1 \approx 4,162277 $.

Comment: I assume *adjancency* is a typo for *adjacency*, but what is *agency*? Also, what does "of course" mean in the last sentence? Is the value supposed to be obvious from the matrix?

Comment: Yes, that was typo. It looks like one of the editors fixed it. Thank you. 
Yes, $\lambda_0$  is one of the eigenvalues of $M$ and it is the largest one.

Comment: No one fixed the "adjancency" in the title. But is it supposed to be *obvious* that the largest eigenvalue is $\sqrt{10}+1$?

Comment: Actually, you are right. I have just fixed that. 
I agree, maybe it would be valuable to put all eigenvalues of $M$; that was a shorthand.

Comment: you wrote "Lastly, real roots of  are the following" and listed 3 roots for a degree 10 polynomial.  But $W$ is real symmetric so all roots are real.  Further $\lambda_0$ is simple by Perron Frobenius theory which, checking the trace implies $\lambda_2$ is simple and implies $\lambda_1$ has multiplicity 2.  Conclude a degree 10 polynomial has only 4 complex roots, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using the symmetries in the graph, try out vectors that equal 1 on the first $n$ components and equal a variable $x$ on the last component. The eigenvalue equation gives you two equations and two unknowns; without giving too much away, you’ll end up with a quadratic that you can solve to get the desired eigenvalue.

To prove it is maximal, try using Perron-Frobenius and Courant-Fischer; what do you notice about the entries of the corresponding eigenvector?